# Linux equivalent of Cisco's "begin" command

Tags: text-processing

In the Cisco IOS, you can filter and manipulate the output of commands using various built-in tools.  Some of these have clear Linux equivalents.  For example, 'exclude' and 'include' provide 'grep -v' and 'grep' behavior.

The "begin" command will output all input text **after** it matches a RegEx pattern.  Is there  a Linux equivalent for this type of behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, it's easily done using awk:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd' | awk '{if (p) {print;}} /^b$/ { print; p=1;}'
b
c
d

$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd' | awk '{if (p) {print;}} /^b$/ { p=1;}'
c
d
```

These can also be abbreviated as (thanks to @manatwork):

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd' | awk '/^b$/{p=1} p'
b
c
d

$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd' | awk 'p; /^b$/{p=1}'
c
d
```

Rolling it into a convenient shell script is left as an exercise for the user.

Comment: Thanks to default action that can be written shorter as `awk '/^b$/{p=1} p` or `awk 'p; /^b$/{p=1}`, depending if you want to include the matching line or not. But thanks to pattern ranges `awk '$0=="b",0'` is enough.

Comment: The awk approach comes closest...guess i have to learn more about awk!  I'd ultimately like to include it as a alias in my bashrc.

Answer (score 4):

`grep -A1000 search` gives 999 lines of output after each matching line.

Comment: +1, but why not just bang on the '9' key (`-A99999`) a few times?

Answer (score 3):

Use `less` and then <kbd>/</kbd> to search:

```
petrus@hive:/usr/bin$ ls -l | less
total 535796
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root        30244 2011-02-23 14:22 [
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root            8 2011-05-26 01:22 2to3 -> 2to3-2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root           96 2011-04-11 21:07 2to3-2.7
[...]
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root         9588 2011-02-24 09:43 appres
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root         6930 2011-05-20 23:53 apr-1-config
:
```

And now by typing <kbd>/</kbd>, the 'less' prompt (`:`) will change. If I search "lsusb":

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root         9588 2011-02-24 09:43 appres
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root         6930 2011-05-20 23:53 apr-1-config
/lsusb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root           13 2011-05-26 01:24 lsusb -> ../sbin/lsusb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       114528 2010-11-24 18:16 ltrace
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy in sed: print all lines from the first line matching the pattern to the last line (`$`).

```
sed -n '/pattern/,$p'
```

If you want to omit the line matching the pattern, delete everything up to and including it.

```
sed '1,/pattern/d'
```